# WordPress plugin management not working anymore

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress version 4.8.4. In a while, I've experienced some issues in the plugin management panel: I can't manage them at all, no enable/disable, it's impossible to remove or install them.
What can be wrong? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is changing back to the default theme for any conflicts. If that resolves the issue, you would then disable all plugins and switch back to your theme. Enable each plugin one by one until it breaks again.

If that doesn't work you can turn off all plugins via PHPMyAdmin with the following mySQL statement

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

You can run the same query direct in MySQL if you don't have PHPMyadmin.

That will turn off all plugins, then at that point you would do the same as mentioned above. Turn them on one by one until it breaks.

It's usually caused by JS conflicts with plugins and themes. Some plugins might load their scripts as a higher priority than your theme loads its own resources. After that then you would probably need the WordPress forums.

PhilB